# Possible values for platform.machine()

Tags: python

> [`platform.machine()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/platform.html#platform.machine)
>   Returns the machine type, e.g. 'i386'. An empty string is returned if the value cannot be determined.

What are the possible values for this field?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

On platforms with `os.uname()`, this information [comes directly from the result of that API call](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/platform.py#L912). That is to say, `platform.machine()` returns the same thing as the `uname -m` command.

Thus, the answer really depends on the kernel's implementation of the `uname(2)` system call. For that, see this question and answer:

**[Possible values for `uname -m` (utsname.machine)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45125516/119527)**

Comment: This answers the questions for the possible values on Linux (and likely Mac which also has `uname`), but what about on Windows?

Comment: The list you reference is very incomplete and does not fully match with `platform.machine()`. Why is this the accepted answer?!

Comment: @mara004 When you submit an answer that is more complete, I will be happy to accept it.

Comment: I'm not, unfortunately. If I already knew the answer I wouldn't be searching here...

Answer (score 1):

Possible values are listed [there](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uname). For Unix and Linux based OSs, `platform.machine()` gives you the same answer than the command `uname -m`.

For Windows though it's a bit more complicated. `uname` doesn't exist on this platform and though Cygwin gives you the possibility to use `uname -m` it won't give you the same result as `platform.machine()` (respectively x86_64 and AMD64 on my Windows machine).
That's because of [a choice made with the platform module](https://bugs.python.org/issue7146).