# Possible values for `uname -m`

Tags: linux, unix

The [`uname(1)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/uname.1.html) command-line utility has a `-m` option which prints the "machine hardware name".

On Linux, this field comes from the `machine` member of `struct utsname`, as populated by the [`uname(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/uname.2.html) system call.

Many other language APIs return this information:

- Python: [`os.uname()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.uname) and [`platform.machine()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/platform.html#platform.machine)
- PHP: [`php_uname()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.php-uname.php)

**What are the possible values for the "machine" field?**

Comment: Python's `os.uname()` has caused Jack Lloyd a fair amount of trouble in determining the OS and platform when configuring the [Botan library](https://github.com/randombit/botan). Linux and BSDs are OK, but others seem to provide inconsistent results, like MinGW, Cygwin, Solaris, Dragonfly, etc. You might want to have a look at [botan/configure.py](https://github.com/randombit/botan/blob/master/configure.py). If its any consolation, Cmake is even worse.

Comment: @jww I'm curious if this is still true several years later.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

## Linux

(v4.12 - 2017-July)

Let's refer to the source of the [newuname](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v4.12/source/kernel/sys.c#L1148) system call.

Tracking this down is complicated by the fact that Linux has [UTS namespaces](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/183717/whats-a-uts-namespace), but the [`init_uts_ns`](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v4.12/source/init/version.c#L25) `machine` field is initialized by the `UTS_MACHINE` macro, which is defined per-architecture.

Further complicating matters, `machine` can be overridden via  [`override_architecture()`](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v4.12/source/kernel/sys.c#L1109), if the process is running under a 32-bit "compat" personality, to `COMPAT_UTS_MACHINE`.

`UTS_MACHINE` defaults in `Makefile` to the same thing as `ARCH`. However, many platforms have separate sub-architectures under the same `arch` directory, so they set `UTS_MACHINE` themselves

With the list of directories in `arch/` and a little `grep`-ing of the Linux kernel sources (`git grep 'UTS_MACHINE\s*:='` and `git grep COMPAT_UTS_MACHINE`), we can arrive at this list:

- `alpha`
- `arc`
- `arm`
- `aarch64_be` (`arm64`)
- `aarch64` (`arm64`)
- `armv8b` (`arm64` compat)
- `armv8l` (`arm64` compat)
- `blackfin`
- `c6x`
- `cris`
- `frv`
- `h8300`
- `hexagon`
- `ia64`
- `m32r`
- `m68k`
- `metag`
- `microblaze`
- `mips` (native or compat)
- `mips64` (`mips`)
- `mn10300`
- `nios2`
- `openrisc`
- `parisc` (native or compat)
- `parisc64` (`parisc`)
- `ppc` (`powerpc` native or compat)
- `ppc64` (`powerpc`)
- `ppcle` (`powerpc` native or compat)
- `ppc64le` (`powerpc`)
- `s390` (`s390x` compat)
- `s390x`
- `score`
- `sh`
- `sh64` (`sh`)
- `sparc` (native or compat)
- `sparc64` (`sparc`)
- `tile`
- `unicore32`
- `i386` (`x86`)
- `i686` (`x86` compat)
- `x86_64` (`x64`)
- `xtensa`

Comment: .... for the current generation of Linux.  There have doubtless been other values in the past, and will doubtless be other values in the future.

Comment: @StephenC Absolutely. In my case, I had a few architectures in mind, and wanted to know how to best detect them. Specifically, I say `if platform.machine().startswith('ppc')`, then it's PowerPC, and `if platform.machine().startswith('arm')` then it's ARM.

Comment: Actually, it is better to tabulate this by Linux kernel version than by date.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart - this is going to get like browser identification strings soon - for example, 'aarch64' is an ARM architecture, but doesn't start with or contain 'arm'. For x86-like CPUs, we have i386, i686 or x86_64 (though my windows install of python returns AMD64).

Comment: This list is missing `armv7l`, reported f.ex. by Raspberry Pi 4 running in 32-bit mode

Comment: Another list can be found at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uname

Comment: That's a +40 well deserved.

Comment: Yes, missing `armv7l`, running on Raspberry Pi 3B+ as default.