# How to detect 386, amd64, arm, or arm64 OS architecture via shell/bash

Tags: bash, shell, arm, posix, x86-64

I'm looking for a POSIX shell/bash command to determine if the OS architecture is `386`, `amd64`, `arm`, or `arm64`?

Comment: This is not quite a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/45125525, but it is similar.

Answer (score 116):

I suggest using:

```
dpkg --print-architecture
```

Comment: And more accurate: `uname -m` outputs `aarch64` on Raspberry instead of `arm64`.

Comment: @PouriyaZarbafian in what sense is that "more accurate" ?

Comment: @YoloPerdiem you're right, apparently they're the same thing.

Comment: @PouriyaZarbafian That's not what I meant.  They are not equivalent. https://github.com/lxc/lxc/issues/129

Comment: @YoloPerdiem they're the same in the specific case that I was mentioning (Raspberry), but according to your link `dpkg --print-architecture` would be more accurate as the question is about OS architecture.

Comment: Will this work on non debian distro ?

Comment: `uname -m` outputs `aarch64` on mu ubuntu 22 parallels guest image running on my macbook pro M1max.

Answer (score 79):

```
uname -m
```

prints values such as `x86_64`, `i686`, `arm`, or `aarch64`.

Comment: Humm, so on a Raspberry pi output is `armv7l`. Would that be arm or arm64?

Comment: @Justin 64-bit was introduced in ARM v8, so `armv7l` means 32-bit little-endian ARM. That being said, if you're on an RPi3: the processor is actually 64-bit, but if your OS is in 32-bit mode it reports an older model.

Comment: aarch64 is the same as arm64 (64-bit ARM) armv71 is 32-bit ARM

Comment: This works great on macOS until you have the terminal app running through Rosetta... it will return x86_64...

Answer (score 37):

I went with the following:

```
architecture=""
case $(uname -m) in
    i386)   architecture="386" ;;
    i686)   architecture="386" ;;
    x86_64) architecture="amd64" ;;
    arm)    dpkg --print-architecture | grep -q "arm64" && architecture="arm64" || architecture="arm" ;;
esac
```

Comment: While you're at it, you might as well collapse the first two branches in your case logic to

`i386 | i686)   architecture="386" ;;`

It's always good to include a catch-all branch at the end, too, to the effect of

`*)   echo "Unable to determine system architecture."; exit 1 ;;`

Comment: On my Intel machine `uname -m` == "x86_64"

Comment: @DUzun: That's correct, x86_64 and amd64 are basically synonyms.  AMD developed the ISA initially, then Intel implemented it, so some software still uses "amd64" as the architecture name.  This is unrelated to whether your AMD64 CPU was sold by Intel, AMD, Via, Zhaoxin, or is emulated by QEMU or Bochs or whatever on totally different hardware.  See [The most correct way to refer to 32-bit and 64-bit versions of programs for x86-related CPUs?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53364320)

Comment: `uname -m` on RPi4B w Ubuntu returns `aarch64`, not `arm`.

Comment: `unset architecture`
`clear`
`case "$(uname -m)" in`
`    i386|i686)      pc_arch=386;;`
`    x86_64)         pc_arch=amd64;;`
`    aarch64|arm)    sudo dpkg --print-architecture | grep -q arm64 && pc_arch=arm64 || pc_arch=arm;;`
`    *)`
`                    clear`
`                    printf "%s\n\n" 'Failed to detect this pc'\''s architecture using the command: "${uname -m}"'`
`                    return 1`
`                    ;;`
`esac`
`clear`
`printf "%s\n\n" "The pc's architecture is: ${pc_arch}/$(uname -m)"`

Answer (score 8):

```
$ lscpu | grep Architecture

Architecture:                    x86_64
```

Or if you want to get only the value:

```
 $ lscpu | awk '/Architecture:/{print $2}'

x86_64
```

Answer (score 6):

```sh
$ arch
```

Also works. Tested on Debian-based and RPM-based distros.

Comment: With `arch` you get the architecture of the current terminal. The real OS architecture may be different

Answer (score 3):

```
uname -m
```

This will display the machine hardware name, which will indicate the processor architecture.

If the output is "arm", it means the processor architecture is ARM-based. If the output is "x86_64", it means the processor architecture is AMD-based (also known as x86-64 or Intel 64).

Comment: There's already [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48678152/how-to-detect-386-amd64-arm-or-arm64-os-architecture-via-shell-bash/48679326#48679326) that suggests using `uname -m`.  Actually two answers, one having a `switch` statement.

Comment: what if it's says "aarch64"?