# What are the possible values of CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR?

Tags: cmake

In CMake, what are the different possible values of `CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR`? At least, the values for common processor families by AMD, Intel, Apple, Qualcomm and such?

I couldn't find this information in the [CMake documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR.html).

Answer (score 12):

According to the [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR.html), "when not cross-compiling, this variable has the same value as the `CMAKE_HOST_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR` variable". In the former scenario, the variable is set by the toolchain file, which I assume is what you're interested in doing.

In the latter case, the [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_HOST_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR.html) says that `CMAKE_HOST_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR` is determined by inspecting the environment in the following way:

- On Windows, the value of the `PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE` environment variable is used.

  - The options are: `AMD64`, `IA64`, `ARM64`, `EM64T`, `X86`. Source: [this SuperUser answer](https://superuser.com/a/1441469/207843).
- On macOS, the value of `uname -m` is used by default. However, since this might vary based on whether you're using x86 or ARM CMake, version 3.19.2+ will use the value of `CMAKE_APPLE_SILICON_PROCESSOR` (either CMake or environment variable) instead, if it is set. It also normalizes `Power Macintosh` to `powerpc`.

  - As far as I am aware, the possible values here are `x86_64`, `arm64`, and `powerpc`.
- On OpenBSD, it uses the `arch -s` command.

  - Not sure what the full list is here. Unfortunately, the [man page](https://man.openbsd.org/machine.1) doesn't have anything to say about this.
- On Linux and related systems (Cygwin, MSYS, Android, GNU), it uses `uname -m`

  - This has *many* possible values. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45125525/2137996
- Otherwise, it looks for the `uname` command and tries `uname -p` first. If it returns a non-zero exit status, it resorts to `uname -m`

  - No telling what this could be.

But what really matters is how CMake will *use* the value of `CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR`. Here are the functions I'm aware of:

- The default value of `CPACK_SYSTEM_NAME` is `${CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME}-${CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR}`.
- The language modules `Modules/CMake<LANG>Information.cmake` all optionally include platform modules suffixed with `-${CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR}.cmake`

  - In most cases, no such modules exist. On Android, very many platform modules exist with processor-specific variants.
- The FindJNI module uses it to guide its search
- It is passed to ARMClang via `--mcpu` (compile) and `--cpu` (link)

Comment: `Source: this SuperUser answer.` it's really clear in the source: https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/blob/master/Modules/CMakeDetermineSystem.cmake#L35 -> `$ENV{PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE}` on windows.

Comment: @KamilCuk - that is the source only for the possible values of `PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE`

Comment: But - how can it make sense for this value to be OS-dependent? It's supposed to only depend on the actual processor architecture.

Comment: @einpoklum - That is a question for the CMake developers. I don't understand why the values aren't normalized either.

Comment: @AlexReinking: Ok, fair enough, but how can we use these non-normalized values? Check all the variations for each processor we care about? (I guess that's a rhetorical question.)

Comment: @einpoklum - I guess that depends on what you're trying to do with that information. If you're interested in determining available instruction sets, for example, you might find `CheckSourceCompiles` to be less brittle.